# How to correctly create an instance of a class with exec() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, class-method

I'm making a GUI using the TKinter library from Python. I want the user to select an option from a Combobox and then, to press a Button, which should create an instance of a class named as the selected option. In order to save code, I decided to use the `exec()` fuction in this way:
`exec('instance = ' + comboExample.get() + '()')`.
This starts the `__init__()` method of the class, but when I try to call an other method (in this case from an inherited class) using `instance.method()` it displays the following error: `NameError: name 'instance' is not defined`. Here you have an example of the script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

master = Tk()

#Create classes
class Base():
    def method(self):
        self.label = Label(master, text = self.sentence)
        self.label.pack()

class Example1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Example1 created')
        self.sentence = 'This is example 1.'

class Example2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Example2 created')
        self.sentence = 'This is example 2'

#Create Combobox and Button
combo = ttk.Combobox(master, state = 'readonly')
combo['values'] = ['Example1', 'Example2']
combo.pack()

def callback():
    exec('instance = ' + combo.get() + '()')
    #Here is the error
    instance.method()

button = Button(master, command = callback, text = 'Button')
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

I don't now why but when I try with the following code it works properly:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'This is an example'
    def add_text(self):
        print(self.text)

exec('instance = Example()')
instance.add_text()
```

At the moment, I've only found one solution, which consists in not using `exec()`, but makes me waste more code than using it, especially if I want to create a lot of classes like `Example1` and `Example2`. It's all like the previous big script, but changing the `callback()` function:

```
def callback():
    if combo.get() == 'Example1':
        instance = Example1()
    if combo.get() == 'Example2':
        instance = Example2()
    instance.method()
```

That's all. I started programming in Python only 2 months ago and I'm also new in stackoverflow, so if I've made some mistake in the explanation or anything, please tell me and I'll fix it.
Thanks for your time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you only started programming two months ago, you definitely shouldn't be using `exec`. `exec` has it's uses, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: You can’t use `exec` to create new local variables.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to do what I want without using `exec`?

Comment: Is there any way to create a global variable from a function?

Comment: ARD: While it is possible to create a global variable in a function, that approach is also not a good idea for several reasons. You just need a way to associate user entered strings to the desired classes. In Python a dictionary to define the mapping from one to the other would be a excellent way to accomplish it.

Comment: Side note you would be better of using `format()` for string formatting instead of the `+` concatenation method. This can prevent issues with data type errors and make it easier to read for longer strings with multiple variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn’t your syntax; it’s that you’re trying to do something illegal. You can’t create new local variables with `exec`. (The reason the same code outside a function works is that in general you *can* create a new global variable with `exec`, but it’s still a bad idea.)

But you also don’t *need* to do that. In Python, everything is an object, including classes. So, you just need the get the class from the name. Then you can create an instance of that class, and store it in a local variable, by just using the same normal syntax you’d use for instantiating a class statically and storing it in a local variable.

---

The right way to do this is to store a dictionary mapping names to class objects. If you want to get clever, you can write a decorator that registers classes with that dictionary, but if that sounds like Greek to you, just do it explicitly:

```
classes = {'Spam': Spam, 'Eggs': Eggs}
```

If you have dozens of these, you can avoid the repetition with a comprehension like this:

```
from your_module import Spam, Eggs
classes = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in (Spam, Eggs)}
```

… but at that point you’re probably better off learning how to write the decorator.

Either way, you can fill your combo box with the keys of that dictionary instead of repeating yourself in the `combo['values']` line.

And then, to create an instance, you just do this:

```
cls = classes[comboExample.get()]
instance = cls()
```

(Obviously you can collapse that into a single line, but I thought it would be easier to understand if we keep the two parts separate.)

---

If you really want to do this in a hacky way, you can. Every class that you’ve created in this module is already stored in a dictionary by name—the module’s global namespace. That’s the same place you were trying to find it implicitly with `exec`, but you can find it explicitly by just looking it up in `globals()`. However, the global namespace also has the names of all of your functions, imported modules, top-level constants and variables, etc., so this is usually a bad idea. (Obviously, `exec` has the exact same problems.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the script works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `exec` for this purpose. `exec` is a powerful tool, but it's the wrong tool for this job.

A much simpler approach is to create a mapping from user inputs to classes. You can then use that mapping both for the combobox and for the callback.

Example:

```
...
mapping = {"Example1": Example1, "Example2": Example2}

#Create Combobox and Button
combo = ttk.Combobox(master, state = 'readonly')
combo['values'] = sorted(mapping.keys())
combo.pack()

def callback():
    class_name = combo.get()
    cls = mapping[class_name]
    instance = cls()
    instance.method()
...
```

You could even automatically generate the mapping by iterating over a list of classes, though for this example that seems like overkill.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the script works perfectly.